# Can a curve on $n$-sphere be uniquely defined by a "direction" vector?

Tags: soft-question, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Let $\mathbb{S}^n=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\colon\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert^2=1\}$ be the unit $n$-sphere and $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}^\prime\in\mathbb{S}^n$ two points on it.

I would like to investigate if it possible to define a unique $n$-dimensional vector, living in a tangent space (like the ones shown in the figure below), so as "traveling" across the dashed geodesic is possible without defining a new "direction" at any given point of $\mathbb{S}^n$ (e.g., on $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}^\prime$).

[image]

As an analogy, I'm thinking of the Euclidean $n$-dimensional space, where a given vector is "enough" to define a unique direction. Roughly speaking, we can think that if we let an object move forward/backward on a given direction (i.e., defined by a single vector), then no further information (i.e., a different vector) is needed at any given point of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Similarly, my intuition says that if a single direction (in terms of a vector that belongs to the tangent space at a given point of $\mathbb{S}^n$) is given to a point of $\mathbb{S}^n$, then we can travel along a geodesic and arrive at the same point, without the need to change "direction", as long as we stay on the surface of the manifold. Thus, I wonder if what I mentioned about the Euclidean space is possible in this non-Euclidean manifold (or even in other non-Euclidean manifolds, like n-torus etc), and what would be the minima conditions for that. For instance, in the Euclidean space example, we need to define an $n$-dimensional vector.

In other words: can the geodesic on $\mathbb{S}^n$ shown above be defined uniquely by a vector?

Comment: I have not read carefully but this seems like a geodesic question?

Comment: @User203940, yes, probably. I'm sorry I'm not familiar with Riemannian geometry, this could be even trivial in this area.

Comment: Don't apologize! It's good to explore and it's good to rediscover (or discover) things. I was just offering what little insight I had based on a quick read.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the pictured curve is not a geodesic.

Comment: @Kajelad, thanks, you are right, I will fix it.

Comment: A single tangent vector to the curve is not enough, if it is not bound by any other restriction. However, knowing its derivative at every point is enough, for a curve in the sphere.

Comment: @Laz, this is due to the constant curvature of sphere? So, is the sphere the only non-Euclidean manifold that allows that? Thanks!

Comment: I think it follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. If you know the derivative $\gamma'$, you know $\gamma$ up to an additive constant which will be determined easily by knowing that at every value of $t$ the point $\gamma(t)$ lies in $\mathbb{S}^n$. But I think this condition could be weakened, it certainly is a lot to know its derivative at every point.

Comment: @Laz, thanks, I understand. But that holds vice verse, right? Can you uniquely determine a geodesic curve using a direction at a single point?

Comment: If you know $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma'(0)$, then yes. A geodesic is a solution to a 2nd order ODE with smooth defining vector field, so these initial conditions determine it entirely, by the Fundamental Theorem of Existence and Uniqueness of ODEs. But maybe you need to know some Riemannian Geometry to understand this, as the geodesic equation in a manifold that is not $\mathbb{R}^n$, usually implies understanding affine connections in general.

Comment: @Laz, thanks for all your comment.

Comment: You are welcome. If you decide to study some Riemannian Geometry, I recommend you Manfredo do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, it is a fine book to start.

Comment: @Laz, I have John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds by my side right now, I just need to decide to start studying it... :)